# Different estimation methods of Time series model

Tags: time-series

This question might be a huge topic, but let's talk about the simple case, say AR (auto-regressive) model. Usually people have various methods of estimating the AR model, like Burgs algorithm, Yule walker algorithm, or even OLS (ordinary least squares). Could some one tell me what is the motivation of using so many different skills to estimate the same model. Is there any literature of book discussing these topic?

Thanks a lot,